# Search query in Elastic Search

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I am creating a search on website based on ElasticSearch, and I am very new to ElasticSearch so I would be happy for any help.

This is a structure of my ElasticSearch content:

```
hits:   
    0:  
        _index: "mysite"
        _type:  "products"
        _id:    "1"
        _score: 1
        _source:    
            name:   
                0:  "This is name"
            number: "N6"
            status: "Y"
```

And this is my Perl script:

```
my $e = Search::Elasticsearch->new();

my $results = $e->search(
    index => 'mysite',
    type => 'products',
    size => 3,
        body  => {
                query => {
                        match => { name => $query }
                }
        }
);
```

I would like to ask you how to make script that it match **only** products which have a **status "Y"** and it should find a **substring** of name, for example if `$query` contains "is", it should find that product because that product contains "is" in name "This is name", and the last one, it should search for **number** too, for example if `$query` contains "N6", it should find that product too.

So something like this: **(name OR number) AND status = "Y"**

Thank you very much.

**Update**

I rewrite it to Perl syntax, but I have a syntax error :/

```
  query => {
      query_string => {
          query => {
            (name => $word OR number => $word) AND status => "Y"
          }
      }
  }
```

Error:

```
-evalfile error: syntax error at (eval 215) line 33, near "} OR "\nGlobal symbol "$e" requires explicit package name at (eval 215) line 40.
```

Comment: Is the syntax error in Perl or Elasticsearch? Also please post the error.

Comment: It looks that it is a Perl error, posted. I think that syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query using the [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query). There are quite a few other options from the documentation. The ability to search on some keywords will depend on the field mapping you have setup as well.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "name:is AND (state:Y OR number:N6)"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to treat the whole `query_string` query as a string. So the query would look something like this:

```
my $e = Search::Elasticsearch->new();

my $results = $e->search(
    index => 'mysite',
    type => 'products',
    size => 3,
    body  => {
        query => "(name:$word OR number:$word) AND status:Y"
    }
);
```

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

[filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-filter-context.html) are what you want:

```
PUT myindex/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [{ 
        "should": [{ 
          "match": {"name": "is" },
          "term": {"number": "N6"}
        }],
        "must": {
          "term": {"status": "Y"}
        }        
      ]}
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes you've made `number` and `status` as unanalyzed string or keyword types (depends on [version](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)) - which you should if there are a discrete number of values within those fields. Otherwise, swap `term` for `match`.

Comment: What is difference between query_string and filters? What is faster?

Comment: Error: bool query does not support [filter]